# Convert datetime to ISO format

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, datetime-parsing

I have a date in format `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss` and I need to convert it to ISO format, but it's not working correctly.
Here is my code:

```
let date = '12.01.2016 0:00:00'; //12 January 2016
let parsedDate = moment(date, 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss')
console.log(parsedDate.toISOString()); //result is 2016-12-31T23:00:00.000Z
```

example2:

```
let date = '12.01.2016 0:00:00'; //12 January 2016
let parsedDate = new Date(date)
console.log(parsedDate.toISOString()); //result is 2016-11-30T23:00:00.000Z
```

Where is the problem? Why do I get different results?

Comment: Think about the timezone you're in vs GMT. For me, someone living in the GMT timezone, this code works correctly. --- The second example, the first reports the wrong year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [format parameter](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) is wrong, use `'DD.MM.YYYY H:mm:ss'` instead.

There is no lowercase `dd`, use uppercase `DD` for day of month and use uppercase `YYYY` for year instead of lowercase `yyyy`.

Please note that [`toISOString()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/):

> Note that `.toISOString()` always returns a timestamp in UTC, even if the moment in question is in local mode. This is done to provide consistency with the specification for native JavaScript Date .`toISOString()`, as outlined in [the ES2015 specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.toisostring).

```js
let date = '12.01.2016 0:00:00'; //12 January 2016
let parsedDate = moment(date, 'DD.MM.YYYY H:mm:ss')
console.log(parsedDate.toISOString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tried using moment.js and it seems you used a mask as you'd use in C# for example. Moment.js uses capitals in the date parts.

```
let date = '12.01.2016 0:00:00'; //12 January 2016
let parsedDate = moment(date, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss');
console.log(parsedDate.toISOString()); //result is 2016-01-11T23:00:00.000Z
```

The [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) function requires another kind of input.

Answer (score 0):

In the second example, the parsed date results in December 1, 2016 0:00:00 (GMT+1)

When you output toISOString() it gives you the GMT time, which is 1 hour earlier, hence the November 30, 2016 23:00:00

Comment: 2 hours earlier?

Comment: @evolutionxbox sorry, 1 hour, edited. For me it's 2 hours, because of my timezone

Answer (score 0):

Look this link https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp , paragraph 'ISO Dates'

> Omitting T or Z in a date-time string can give different result in different browser.